# When projecting contents in Angular 11, is it possible to get a reference to elements identified by a template variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a scenario where Component A projects some elements into Component B. I would like to display all such elements, and get a reference to elements identified by template variables (#content, #button).

Component A's template:

```
<app-component-b>
  <div #content></div>
  <button #button></button>
</app-component-b>
```

Component B's template:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

From Component B, is it possible to get a reference to the `#content` and `#button` elements?

---

EDIT:
Before posting I'd tried with ViewChild and ContentChild at OnInit time, but I wasn't getting anything back, which made me question if it even was possible. I tried fiddling with it a bit more, and it looks like it works with @ContentChild at AfterViewInit time.

Comment: Have you tried? Does it not work?

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: I edited the post, it looks like it is possible but you have to wait at least for the component's content to be fully initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is achievable at least from AfterContentInit using @ContentChild.

```
export class ComponentB implements OnAfterContentInit {

    @ContentChild('content') content: HTMLDivElement;
    @ContentChild('button') button: HTMLButtonElement;

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        // --> ElementRef, ElementRef
        console.log(this.content, this.button);
    }

}
```

I do not know if this is good practice or a good solution though.